# Converting parquet file to Golang struct with nested elements

Tags: go, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet file with nested arrays/structs in Go using xitongsys/parquet-go library. The list data is not getting read and not seeing the values. Below is my struct in Golang

```golang
type Play struct {
    SID            string   `parquet:"name=si, type=BYTE_ARRAY, convertedtype=UTF8, encoding=PLAIN_DICTIONARY, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL" json:"si,omitempty"`
    TimeStamp      int      `parquet:"name=ts, type=INT64, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL" json:"ts,omitempty"`
    SingleID       int      `parquet:"name=sg, type=INT64, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL" json:"sg,omitempty"`
    PID            int      `parquet:"name=playid, type=INT64, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL" json:"playid,omitempty"`
    StartTimeStamp string   `parquet:"name=startts, type=BYTE_ARRAY,repetitiontype=OPTIONAL"`
    Price          []Price1 `parquet:"name=price, type=LIST, repetitiontype=REQUIRED" json:"price,omitempty"`
}

type Price1 struct {
    CurrID int    `parquet:"name=currId, type=INT64, repetitiontype=REQUIRED" json:"currId,omitempty"`
    LPTag  string `parquet:"name=lptag, type=BYTE_ARRAY,convertedtype=UTF8, repetitiontype=REQUIRED" json:"lptag,omitempty"`
    LPrice Money  `parquet:"name=lpmoney, type=STRUCT" json:"lpmoney,omitempty"`
}

type Money struct {
    AdmCurrCode  string `parquet:"name=admCC, type=BYTE_ARRAY, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL" json:"admCC,omitempty"`
    AdmCurrValue string `parquet:"name=admCV, type=BYTE_ARRAY" json:"admCV,omitempty"`
}
```

CurrID and LPTag are coming as empty even though the parquet file is having valid values

Comment: Can you share the parquet file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `github.com/segmentio/parquet-go` package can read the file correctly. Do you need to stick to the `github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go` package?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/segmentio/parquet-go"
)

type Play struct {
    SID            string  `parquet:"si"`
    TimeStamp      int     `parquet:"ts"`
    SingleID       int     `parquet:"sg"`
    PID            int     `parquet:"playid"`
    StartTimeStamp string  `parquet:"startts"`
    Price          []Price `parquet:"price,list"`
}

type Price struct {
    CurrID int    `parquet:"currId"`
    LPTag  string `parquet:"lptag"`
    LPrice Money  `parquet:"lpmoney"`
}

type Money struct {
    AdmCurrCode  string `parquet:"admCC"`
    AdmCurrValue string `parquet:"admCV"`
}

func main() {
    rows, err := parquet.ReadFile[Play]("s3.parquet")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, c := range rows {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I see that all required fields are getting printed using github.com/segmentio/parquet-go.
I will switch over to this new library.